# How can I fix SSL error, nothing seems to work?

Tags: python, api, ssl, request, urllib

I was just about to do some testing with the Nasa API to see if it works, but I'm getting SSL errors every time I run the code. I tried providing SSL context, and setting verify=False, but nothing seems to work.

Here's the request:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(url=apod["hdurl"], context=ctx) as u, \
    open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(u.read())
```

Above the request, I have defined the context:

```
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
    ctx.check_hostname = False
    ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
```

Since I'm on MacOS I've also tried going Applications > Python 3.8 > Install certificates command, but it doesn't seem to work.
I'm thinking something might be wrong with my Python interpreter.

Also, here's the exception I get:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1124)
```

Seems like the library it's self is having trouble sending requests, if i go:

```
nasa = nasapy.Nasa(key=key)
nasa.picture_of_the_day()
```

I get the same SSL certificate error. How might I go about solving this?

Help much appreciated!

Comment: (a) Which server? (b) Check if your computer's clock is set properly!

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's the Nasa APOD API and my date and time is set to auto, so that's not the issue.

Comment: What is `apod["hdurl"]`?

Comment: Apod is a JSON file, and it grabs the url from it, then accesses it.

Comment: You are not going to give us the URL?

Comment: I don't have the direct URL, it's handled via the nasapy library.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242541/discussion-between-bikger2-and-klaus-d).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, i had to go into the library files venv/bin/api.py and inside the libraries code where the request is, set `verify=False`.

Works now.